# My pendrive is full but when I put it in the laptop it's empty

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I am using the Windows 7 32-bit. I copied some important files to my pendrive a few hours ago. Now, when I connect it to my computer it appears to be empty, but right-clicking the drive and selecting properties shows a lot of space being used. Also I've tested it in Windows XP 32-bit.

I know the files are not hidden. Is there any way to recover these files?

Comment: What makes you think it is _not_ empty?

Comment: @terdon a few hours before I put it on several files, but I do not have any data now

Comment: @terdon I'm really worried becouse It is very important for me.please help me.

Comment: Perhaps the transfer did not work, or you removed the drive before it was finished. It sounds like the files are simply not there. You will get better answers if you explain exactly what you have done in your question, including your operating system.

Comment: [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to the rescue...

Comment: @terdon I've tested it on two systems With two different operating systems but ... :'(

Comment: I edited your question to bring it closer to the desired format here. Please [edit] it yourself and add the operating systems you have tried and what you did. If you don't your question will soon be closed.

Comment: @Breakthrough I've download "TestDisk & PhotoRec 6.14-WIP, Data Recovery" and run it But my pendrive Is still empty.

Comment: In Windows Explorer right click on your drive and go to 'properties'. It will tell you if any space is used. If there is no space used, nothing was transferred and therefore nothing can be recovered.

Comment: @terdon I think it's best I delete my question.

I do not know 
what to do now.

Comment: @user142485 Yes (I know)I've done it
But
It is a large space filled.

Comment: You had not mentioned the most important detail, that the OS is reporting the drive to be full. I have added it to your question. Did you try Breakthrough's suggestion of using TestDisk?

Comment: @terdon yes I've tested it.
But  no avail.

Comment: In that case _say so_ in your question. That's why you are getting downvotes. See [here](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on asking good questions.

Comment: @terdon I'm sorry.
I'm very sad this thread.
For this reason,
I do not focus
I'm sorry that my questions is Minus...I want to cry...
This is terrible

Comment: I've written two articles
I put it on my pendrive
And now I have to start again.
For this reason,
  It is very dreadfully for me.Is there any way to recover these files? @terdon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The files might be hidden

  - Go to your drive
  - then click tools > Folder options...
  - Choose view > and check show hidden files and folders

Screenprint:

[image: screenprint]

Or try running `chkdsk /f /x /r e:\` (or whatever drive letter you got on drive).

Comment: NO, I had previously reviewed. @Homer Simpsons

Comment: run cmd -> then enter dir /s ("YOUR DRIVE LETTER")

Comment: yes, I know.I've done this.

Comment: Download www.ammyy.com and give me your id nr for me to connect live for support

Comment: Wow, thank you @Homer Simpsons But I decided, I write paper again
 Because I have rushing -<@

Comment: Ok last but not least try with recovery always works Homer 0ut